# DatePicker indicate the date of birth in the datepicker, and then display the number of days for the next birthday and the birthday?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

My question is how to do the calculation to show me the age after selecting on the Datepiker I already have the days left for the next birthday now I wanted to do to show me the next birthday. here is my code

```
 TextView aniv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaniv);
    TextView dias =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.diasfaltam);

    // Resource Recovery
SharedPreferences dados=getSharedPreferences("info",0);
int dia = dados.getInt("dia",0);
//para mes ficar com a nomeração "normal"
int mes = dados.getInt("mes",0)+1;
int ano = dados.getInt("ano",0);

aniv.setText(dia + "/" + mes + "/" +ano);



// Perform account to determine how many days are left until the birthday
// Create two instances in the calendar
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();



// Let's get the current system date
int anoatual =cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mesatual =cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int diaatual =cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



// need to check if the birthday has already occurred or not this year
if(mesatual>mes-1) {
anoatual=anoatual+1;
}

if(mesatual==mes-1&&diaatual>dia){
anoatual=anoatual+1;
}


// set the next anniversary date, based on the retrieved data
cal1.set(anoatual, mes-1, dia);

// You need to represent the date in milliseconds to be able to make the difference between them
long milis1 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
long milis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();

// Calculate the difference between the dates
long diff = milis1 - milis2;



// convert the difference in milliseconds to days
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


// Test the displayed result, to check that there are no errors in the calculations
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"number of days until anniversary
" +diffDays,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
dias.setText(""+diffDays);
}
```

this is what i get for ex Still 200 days for your 12/07/1990 birthday.
and i wont to obtain Still 200 days for your 37th birthday.

[what i pretend to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gkgI.png)

Comment: Hi, how do you want to show "... for your 37th birthday." while you didn't provide any information how old is he/she?

Comment: hello i chose the date in the datepicker, but i dont know how to make the calculation to show me that for exemple i chose 1992/20/09 and show s me that is going to be the 28th birthday

Answer (score 0):

In my last app I converted the date to milliseconds, which is a Long value and I subtracted from the today's date in milliseconds the birthday also in milliseconds.

Comment: hello insipre_coding thanks for answering i tried to do that but i think i m putting it in the wrong place or doing it wrong  can you show me please. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it is to add this:

```
cal1.set(ano,mes,dia);
aniv.setText((((cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis())
/ (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 365) +1) + "º");
```